What can be the .atm file extension?
I found an old backup drive of mine, and it is filled with files that end in .atm.
These are most likely from an old phone of mine (can't remember which type), and the full filenames look like: VIDEO0028.mp4.atm, VIDEO0003.3gp.atm and IMAG0172.jpg.atm etc.
Any ideas what these could be? and how to open them?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Have you done any research regarding these files prior to asking? What did you learn? Do the sizes of the files indicate anything, like the mp4 being larger than the jpg? Have you tried simply renaming them to remove the .atm suffix? Have you tried a flexible video player like VLC, or image viewer like IrfanView to view them?

I have done it all - checked the suggested file extensions online, none of them are relevant. Tried removing the atm suffix, the files won't open. Tried renaming it to zip or rar, same result. The file sizes correspond to the second last extension (ie. video extensions are bigger than jpg ones)
